# Как получить колонку с датами и значениями из таблицы, где есть только даты начала и конца периода?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица в виде

| date | from | to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2023 |  | A |
| 03.01.2023 | A | B |
| 05.01.2023 | B | C |
| 07.01.2023 | C |  |

И таблица с датами

Как получить таблицу вида

| date | project |
| --- | --- |
| 01.01.2023 | A |
| 02.01.2023 | A |
| 03.01.2023 | B |
| 04.01.2023 | B |
| 05.01.2023 | C |
| 06.01.2023 | C |
| 07.01.2023 |  |

Comment: Рекурсивным CTE.

Comment: если поддерживается